# How can I generate Code Property Graph (CPG) for a Python source code?

Tags: python, graph, static-analysis

Is there any CPG tool for the Python language? We have tools for Java and C/C++ like Plume, PROGEX, and Joern. But I could not find any for Python.

Thanks.